# Reverse puzzling: What game is this?

Tags: reverse-puzzling, isomorphism

"Hey, George!" I say. "Wanna play a game?"

"Always. What've you got?"

I take out a deck of cards, pull out the A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 of spades, and place them on the table.

[image: source: wikipedia snip]

"So these cards represent the numbers 1 to 9---"

"In what order?" asks George. He's a little pedantic.

"The obvious one," says I. "We take it in turns to pick up a card from the table. **The first person to get three cards that add up to 15 wins.**"

"Oh," George sounded disappointed.

"What?"

"It's so trivial. Easy draw."

"Really? I thought it was quite interesting."

"Not at all. It's basically just a game of ..."

George then explained how this game was simply a disguised version of another well-known game, long since solved.

> What well-known game is it, and how does the equivalence work? Bonus for the best opening moves if your opponent plays randomly rather than strategically.

And when I say "bonus", I really mean the admiration of your peers on PSE, because I'm not going to be giving any other bonuses.

Comment: I didn't even realize it worked like that! Such a weird bijection!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a card version of

> Tic-Tac-Toe  (AKA Naughts and Crosses)

If we arrange the cards like this:

> `2♠` `7♠` `6♠`
>  `9♠` `5♠` `A♠`
>  `4♠` `3♠` `8♠`

We get a

> Magic Square, where each row, column, or diagonal sums to 15.
>  Drawing a card is equivalent to placing your mark ('X' or 'O') in that cards spot in the magic square.

Comment: I thought that Roshambo was another name for rock-paper-scissors, not for this.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You are correct. I even googled it ahead of time, but apparently my brain just decided all three-word-name children's games were the same...